# Return Column Name for column with largest value and criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Return Column Name for column using  largest value and criteria

=INDEX(MIP!$BZ$3:$CG$3,0,MATCH(MAX(MIP!$BZ$1:$CG$1),MIP!$BZ$1:$CG$1,0))

Not able to put in a criteria for the same

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: Microsoft excel 2013

Comment: And what are the criteria you are trying to add?

Comment: i was trying to get the Column Header , using highest value and city as criteria

Comment: Not really helpful. You need to add a couple of IF functions in there but since you haven't indicated what cells might be involved, it's hard to be specific. Basically `=INDEX(MIP!$BZ$3:$CG$3,0,MATCH(MAX(IF(some_range="city name",MIP!$BZ$1:$CG$1)),IF(some_range="city name",MIP!$BZ$1:$CG$1),0))`

Comment: how to share the file

Comment: Can't you just tell us where the city names are and what you are trying to filter by?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BL2ovvz2b-_nsLJZCsXrsxRv1MatpcVn/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110628528653647347974&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: link for the excel sheet

Comment: I don't follow what you want. None of the cells referred to in the formula are city specific. Best guess would be: `=INDEX(H$4:J$4,0,MATCH(MAX(INDEX($H$5:$J$6,MATCH(A6,$G$5:$G$6,0),0)),INDEX($H$5:$J$6,MATCH(A6,$G$5:$G$6,0),0),0))`

Comment: i want according to city name to retrieve the column header name using the highest value, i am not to able to put city in this formula

Comment: Did you try what I posted?

Comment: yes , but when i try to increase the range it doesn't work                      https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BqqEkgdA8w5zQ_1xDTyqk-FuYYos76O_/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110628528653647347974&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I suggest you add totals per city above your table (using SUMIF) then refer to those in your original formula.

Comment: Hi Can you help with formula

Comment: Hi RORY Can u help with FORmulA

Comment: For example: `=sumif($G5:$G,"Bangalore",H5:H)`